# How to set the subplot min and max limits based on the biggest value in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot 6 graphs using Python matplotlib.subplot function. but I am having sort of setting min and max limit problem. Since sometimes , some of the plots can have a really smaller value than the others , I don't expect subplot function to scale their axes in a way that they could be seen as large as the other plots, but sometimes it sounds reasonable like for the first case you can see :

[image]

in this one only the 5th plot has the biggest value and the other ones  should seem really smaller than that.

but also I may have a case like:

[image]

which all of the plots have more or less the same order.

How could I make a strategy and condition, that for the plots with a limit smaller than a certain value, their plot limit be set to a fixed value? or just make subplot to set the limits equal to the biggest values among all y values ?

Comment: Are you able to post the code, or a reprex? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's only a plt.subplot(611) and so on and then each time a plt.plot(t,X) , but I can't provide the whole code or numbers, cause it gets impossible. for me the concept of handling the limits is important, cause in subplots you decide the limits for each plot individually and this is not so good for my case

Comment: Check `plt.subplots(..., sharey=True)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have used plt.subplot instead of plt.subplots , is there a difference ?

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'bool' object

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x11229668>

Comment: Yes, if you create all subplots via `plt.subplots()` you can easily share the axes.

Comment: I changed the subplot to subplots and added sharey=True , now the code is taking much more time to finish , why ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It wasn't a good option , it overwrote all the plots on eachother

Comment: I have no idea what you did (see [mcve]), but of course `plt.subplots` is a good option. Check the [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)